# Unpickling a dictionary produces sticky values

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

To familiarize myself with Python data structures and popular modules, I'm designing an RPG (yes, at the time I thought it was a novel idea). My 'hero' class has two attributes specifically that aren't behaving consistently before and after saving and loading my gamefile via Pickle. I've carefully verified correct syntax in my code against several examples, and now feel confident that there must be some underlying behavior at work that I don't understand. 
The first attribute of my 'hero' class is inventory, which initializes as an empty list. The second attribute is equipment, which is a dictionary of the form

```
{'Mainhand': '', 'Offhand': '', ... etc.}
```

I can equip and unequip instances of my Gear class by assigning the object as the value of the equipment slot in this dictionary, and everything works beautifully until I try these things from a loaded savefile. If I try to unequip something, the line of code

```
hero.equipment[k] = ''
```

is completely ignored with no error message or crash. I can swap gear, but cannot simply unequip any slot, as I could before saving/loading.

What am I not understanding about how Pickle unpacks saved dictionaries of objects? What is making my values feel so... sticky?

EDIT::
These are the functions that save and load my files based on the hero's name given at startup.

```
def save_game():
    filename = str(hero.name) + ".pkl"
    with open(filename, 'wb') as outfile:
        pickle.dump(hero, outfile)
        print("Progress saved.")
        outfile.close()

def load_game():
    global hero
    filename = input("What did they call you?\n")
    filename = str(filename) + ".pkl"
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
            hero = pickle.load(infile)
            print("Previous progress loaded.")
            infile.close()
    else:
        print("You have no saved progress.")
```

And this is the function that unequips my items (works on new files, not on loaded files)

```
def unequip(self, equipping_str, unequipping_obj):
        if unequipping_obj not in hero.inventory:
            hero.inventory.append(unequipping_obj)
        ohAtkPenalty = 1
        if equipping_str == 'Offhand':
            ohAtkPenalty = 0.70
        hero.melee_boost -= unequipping_obj.melee_atk * ohAtkPenalty
        hero.magic_boost -= unequipping_obj.magic_atk * ohAtkPenalty
        hero.health_regen -= unequipping_obj.health_regen
        hero.mana_regen -= unequipping_obj.mana_regen
        hero.equipment[equipping_str] = '' 
        print("You unequip your ", unequipping_obj.item_name, '.', sep='')
        unequipping_obj.quantity += 1
```

Comment: Try to crearte a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can  verif the behaviour. Edit it into your question. thnks

Comment: Added code... any and all feedback welcome. I would love to get this working!

Comment: Okay, a week of staring at my code didn't do it; posting it here and 10 minutes later I figure it out. 'hero. ...' should be 'self. ...' in that last block of code. Still not sure why errors weren't being thrown, but it's working properly now. Do I need to do anything to close out this question?

Comment: Thats the second reason for an mvce ;) by preparing it, you overthink it again :)  - you can self answer it and accept int in 48h - that way you keep the 2 score on your question. Or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Because unequip() is a method of the hero class, all references to hero attributes should be written as 'self. ...', not 'hero. ...'
The solution is much less exciting than I anticipated, but I greatly appreciate the extra eyes on it.